# Simple stack allocator in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-optimization

My plan is to allocate a fixed amount of static memory at initialization (a few MBs), and use a stack allocator for quick temporary buffers. The idea is to avoid calls to `malloc()` for these kinds of temporary buffers (should be safer this way), but still being able to return it from a function (and then freed) if needed, which I otherwise wouldn't be able to with local arrays.

An allocator based on a stack sounded great for this use case, and should also be quite fast since we're only incrementing a stack pointer and calling `memset()` to zero out the space.

The data I'll be storing on the stack will always be of type uint8_t, so the allocator assumes that's what we want and returns a `uint8_t*` instead of a `void*` like `malloc()` does.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

// Convert megabytes to bytes.
#define MB(x) (x * 1024 * 1024)

// Default size: 2 MB.
static uint8_t Stack[MB(2)];

// Points to the next available memory address.
static uint8_t *StackPointer = Stack;

int32_t GetStackUsage()
{
    // Return the amount of memory used.
    return StackPointer - Stack;
}

int32_t GetStackFree()
{
    // Return the amount of available memory.
    return sizeof(Stack) - GetStackUsage();
}

uint8_t *Alloc(int32_t length)
{
    // Return a null pointer, if memory requested is less than 1 byte.
    if (length < 1) return NULL;

    // Return a null pointer, if there is not enough memory left on the stack.
    if (StackPointer + length > Stack + sizeof(Stack)) return NULL;

    // Get a pointer to the next available address.
    uint8_t *memory = StackPointer;

    // Zero out the memory.
    memset(memory, 0, length);
    
    // Increment stack pointer.
    StackPointer += length;

    return memory;
}

void Dealloc(uint8_t *memory)
{
    // Double free is not a good idea.
    if (memory == NULL) return;

    // Reset stack pointer.
    StackPointer = memory;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Bug: Invalid address computation**

`StackPointer + length > Stack + sizeof(Stack)` for this to be true, `StackPointer + length` points past the end of `Stack + sizeof(Stack)`.  Yet that calculation is *undefined behavior* (UB) as address calculations are only allowed within the object (or 1 past).

`length > sizeof(Stack) - (StackPointer - Stack)` works better.

**Why type `int32_t`?**

Allocation sizes are idiomatically `size_t` in C.  `int32_t` is unfounded.

I could see some rational for `unsigned`, `uint_least32_t` or even `int`, but not `int32_t`. `size_t` remains the best choice for sizing.

**Consider 0 allocation**

I would find such an allocator more useful where `Alloc(0)` did not return `NULL`.   If needed, use `if (length == 0) length++;`.  This way, a `NULL` return is unambiguously an out-of-memory failure.

**Alignment**

OP has "data I'll be storing on the stack will always be of type uint8_t", yet that is in the text and deserves to be in the code as a comment to indicate this restriction.

Consider instead, making useful for all types.

`*alloc()` and friends return a pointer suitable for all alignments.  Research `max_align_t` to find the alignment needed.

Consider quantizing the length:

```
// Something like
if (length % alignof(max_align_t)) {
  length += alignof(max_align_t) - length % alignof(max_align_t);
}
// or 
length = (length + alignof(max_align_t) - 1) & (alignof(max_align_t) - 1);
```

When `length` is an *unsigned* type and since `sizeof(max_align_t)` is certainly a power of 2, `length % sizeof(max_align_t)` results in a fast *and* operation.  So this adjustment is not a costly general purpose `%`.

**Why return `uint8_t *`?**

C allocators far more often return `void *`.

**Speed**

If "should also be quite fast", skip the `memset(memory, 0, length);` part and let the caller zero memory if desired.

**Avoid precedence problems**

Consider the effect of `MB(2 + 3)` -->  `(2 + 3 * 1024 * 1024)`

Better as `#define MB(x) ((x) * 1024 * 1024)`

**Avoid overflow**

`#define MB(x) (x * 1024 * 1024)` is overflow with 16-bit `int`.  Suggest:

```
#define MB(x) ((size_t)1024 * 1024 * (x))
```

**Naming**

Code has `GetStackUsage, GetStackFree, Alloc, Dealloc` which is scattered over that namespace and risks collisions.

Suggest `AllocStack_Usage, AllocStack_Free, AllocStack, AllocStack_Free` or some other uniform naming.

**Header file**

As this is a set of helper routines, form a `AllocStack.h` to show what is exposed to the world and a `AllocStack.c` to show the implementation.

**Deallocating `NULL`**

Code nicely handles `Dealloc(NULL)`.  This is like `free(NULL)` is OK.

**Debugging idea**

`Dealloc()` should expect that the pointer (after the null check)
only grows the stack.  If a `Dealloc()` occurs that shrank the stack, that is certainly an error and could be caught and flagged - maybe with an `assert()`.